# Is it possible to exclude labels with nodeSelector?

Tags: kubernetes

i want to do something like

```
nodeSelector:
  role: "!database"
```

in order to schedule pods on nodes which don't host the database.

Thank you

Answer (score 11):

from here:
https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/assign-pod-node/

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: with-node-affinity
spec:
  affinity:
    nodeAffinity:
      requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
        nodeSelectorTerms:
        - matchExpressions:
          - key: role
            operator: NotIn
            values:
            - database
```

Answer (score 2):

Not right now.

Such a form was initially discussed in [issue #341](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/341) and you can follow [issue #15494](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/15494) to track progress on a more configurable label selector.